# How can I check if a file exists locally using "Environment.UserName" in C#?

Tags: c#

I am stuck on something very simple but cannot seem to find what I am looking for exactly.

I am writing a simple application that will check if a file exists.  It will be used by several users so cannot contain specific usernames.

I can get the current username using:

```
string userName = Environment.UserName;
```

When I use an IF statement to check if the file exists, I receive the error "Unrecognized escape sequence" under the "D" of Documents.

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\"+ userName +"\Documents\test.txt"))
        {
            lblUser.Text = "File exists";
        }
```

Can anyone help point out my stupid mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing against your choosen answer. It points correctly to the original problem, but if your user goes to the Properties page of the Documents folder and change the value in the Path page? The choosen answer fails and there are other concerns like using an hard coded path, using a OS specific path separator. All these kind of problems are avoided if you use the specific framework tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reescape when concatenating.

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\"+ userName +@"\Documents\test.txt"))
```

Answer (score 6):

Do not use Environment.UserName to find the Documents folder.
The user can easily change that location using the OS tools.

Use instead

```
string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string fileToCheck = Path.Combine(docFolder, "test.txt");
if (File.Exists(fileToCheck))
{
     lblUser.Text = "File exists";
}
```

See a doc on [Environment.SpecialFolder enum here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You beat me to it ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell it doesn't happen every day :-)

Comment: Just glancing at the docs, just for reference - `.Personal` might be preferable when available; it is *essentially* the same, but also exists in XNA

Comment: Did you intend that comment to go to the OP?

Comment: Yes, but it is not really important